# Springboot: Using yaml anchors across different spring profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, snakeyaml

I have defined a set of default config properties and a YAML anchor `&configDefault` in my `application.yml` file.

```
config:
    test: &configDefault
        a: default_a
        b: default_b
```

I can use these default values in other spring.profiles by default but if I try to [merge the anchor](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) `<<: *configDefault` and then override value for `config.test.b` as:

```
spring:
    profiles: custom

config:
    <<: *configDefault
        b: custom_b
```

I get `found undefined alias configDefault` when starting the app. My expectation was that since all the default values port over to spring profiles I could re-use my predefined anchors too.

Not sure if I'm doing this wrong or if anchors are not intended to be used this way (I think this would be a nice feature to have to reduce duplication in configs.)

sample project on Github: https://github.com/rakeshsthakur/yaml-anchros, example properties file https://github.com/rakeshsthakur/yaml-anchros/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml

I have simplified projects properties on purpose. A more complex example case would have multiple anchors with defaults and overrides in the default spring profile itself. With additional overrides happening in environment-specific profiles when required.

Is this something I can do? Or should I just copy over the default properties with anchors to each profile separately